# Trying to understand a shell sort

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to understand a shell sort that I found online. This is the code:

```
for(increment = size/2;increment > 0; increment /= 2)
{
    for(i = increment; i<size; i++)
    { 
        temp = array[i];
        for(j = i; j >= increment ;j-=increment)
        {
            //perform the insertion sort for this section
            if(temp < array[j-increment])
            {
                array[j] = array[j-increment];
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

I understand that the first loop keeps dividing the number of elements in the array by 2 until it gets to 1. But I don't really understand the rest of the code.

Comment: put it in debugger, step through the code, and use watch to watch the values of various variables to see how it works :-)

Comment: And use a very small file (5 lines?) with 1 duplicate as your test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read up on [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

The innermost loop performs part of an insertion sort, inserting the element into the (presumably) sorted subarray "to the left" of the starting point, but considering only the elements a multiple of `interval` away. The second loop (`for(i=...`) performs the other half of the insertion sort, advancing through the array; when this loop is finished, the entire array is sorted, but only in the sense that there are no elements out of order separated by a multiple of `interval`. That is, there are no `i` and `k` such that array[i] > array[i+k*interval].

The outermost loop iterates through smaller and smaller intervals, until it does a "full" insertion sort of the whole array.

I suppose the idea of starting with large intervals is to speed up the whole sort by allowing elements that are very big or very small to "leapfrog" large sections of the array rather than creep through every position; how well this works is not immediately obvious...